# Is there a way IE 11 can show the inside of a object like chrome ? Maybe a plugin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ie-developer-tools

In chrome when the Front End people do a Console.Log of an object I can see the whole tree. With IE I only see the word [Object]. Any work around so I can see the tree in IE 11 ?

Comment: console.dir(obj) or console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t"))

Comment: I'm confident you can expand it by clicking on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To display an inspectable JavaScript object, send it to the console using console.dir().

Example: console.dir(obj);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Console.Log is, in my experience, just used to print text to the web console.  In IE11, if you pull up the Developer Tools -> Console, and type the name of the object you want to investigate (either a global object or a function's objects when in debug mode) it will allow you to expand the object's tree, just like if you added it to a Watch in debug mode.

```
> document
```

result:

```
|> [object HTMLDocument {_html5shif: 1, activeElement:...}]
```

If you click the arrow, it expands and shows the full tree.

Comment: `console.log()` in every (most?) browser (except IE < 11) let you expand an object's properties.